# How checkpoint.restore() works in Tensorflow, Neural machine translation with attention

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning Neural machine translation from this tutorial
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention#restore_the_latest_checkpoint_and_test

But there is one part that i could not understand about how to load last checkpoint.

I saw that it use this command to load the saved model

```
# restoring the latest checkpoint in checkpoint_dir
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

But seems it didn't use and output from it.
Maybe something like this for example

```
restored_model = checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

And i saw that they call `translate` method right after `checkpoint.restore`

```
translate(u'hace mucho frio aqui.')
```

So i wonder how is this work, eventhough we didn't do anything after `checkpoint.restore` command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `checkpoint` is an instance of [tf.train.Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint). Somehow you have missed it, check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention#checkpoints_object-based_saving), it does initiate

```
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                                 encoder=encoder,
                                 decoder=decoder)
```

And thus it calls those functions like `.restore` or `.save`.

```
checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)
...
# restoring the latest checkpoint in checkpoint_dir
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

Comment: I saw that they make the `tf.train.Checkpoint` instance, but the part that i do not under stand is that how is the `translate()` method works right after `checkpoint.restore` even we did assign anything back to the model that we created before.

Comment: While creating the checkpoint instance, they pass the model (decoder) too.

Comment: During restoration, the corresponding weight information gets mapped to each en/decoder.

Comment: You mean model in here `class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):`  will update automatically after we call `.restore()` ?

Comment: technically yes.